# How to find/list all the rows based on multiple values on a single column - Mysql Query

Tags: mysql

I have a table which contains userID with their play status as True / False along with competitionID. One user can play multiple competitions. I have to find all the rows who played competitionID 5 & 6 both.

Table: contest_played

| userID | play_status | competitionID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | true | 3 |
| 3 | false | 4 |
| 3 | true | 5 |
| 3 | true | 6 |
| 4 | true | 5 |
| 5 | false | 5 |
| 5 | true | 6 |
| 6 | true | 3 |
| 7 | false | 4 |
| 8 | true | 4 |
| 8 | false | 5 |
| 8 | true | 6 |
| 9 | true | 6 |
| 9 | false | 7 |

Based on above records, I need the result like below,

Result records

| userID | play_status | competitionID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | true | 5 |
| 3 | true | 6 |
| 5 | false | 5 |
| 5 | true | 6 |
| 8 | false | 5 |
| 8 | true | 6 |

The userID who have not played both competitionID 5 & 6 should not be in the result.

Highly appreciate your help.

Comment: Please post your table description and data in text format

Comment: @ErgestBasha IN gives me result of either competitionID 5 or 6. I need only who have played both competitionID 5 & 6.

Comment: post the tables  schema  a proper data sample and the expected  result as text too   (not img only)

Comment: @Sam, that edit is better.  A functional fiddle is even nicer to work with.  Your mysql editor should have a place that shows you the CREATE code and you could just copy it out, and then you could create the query to insert the data pretty simply also, either with a query or by formatting the output in a spreadsheet or text editor.  Also, you should always include a primary key.  You don't always need it, but when you run into a problem you could solve if you had one, you will be really happy you've got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sam, in the future you should include a fiddle with the table structure and sample data, something like this:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=cecab1b197c59c4bad448dec6f8cd3fd

That will help you get answers to your question, faster and probably better ones. Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM contest_played 
WHERE userID IN (
  SELECT userID FROM contest_played
  WHERE competitionID IN (5,6)
  GROUP BY userID
  HAVING count(competitionID) = 2
)
AND competitionID in (5,6);
```

Let me know if this produced the results you wanted.  I was not sure if you wanted to only return results for competitionIDs 5 & 6, or if you wanted to return all results for the users who had played both.  If you want to return all, just remove this line:

`AND competitionID in (5,6)`

Comment: This works perfectly. Point noted regarding fiddle.

Comment: Sure thing, glad it works.  A lot of people will skip questions without them, and especially ones with data presented as images or sometimes they won't include any data at all, or even a structure, which makes it very difficult to answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT t1.userID,
           t1.play_status,
           t1.competitionID
      FROM test_tbl t1
 LEFT JOIN test_tbl t2 ON t1.userID = t2.userID
     WHERE t1.competitionID IN (5, 6)
       AND t2.competitionID IN (5, 6)
  GROUP BY t1.userID,
           t1.play_status,
           t1.competitionID
    HAVING COUNT(t1.competitionID) = 2
  ORDER BY t1.userID,
           t1.competitionID
```